# How to use class with namespace in php?

Tags: php, namespaces, composer-php

I try to create app with structure as below:

```
App
 +--src
      Example.php
 +--vendor
    --
 composer.json
 composer.lock
 index.php
```

Where Example.php set `namespace Example` then use it inside `index.php`.
but it not working.

Example.php

```
<?php namespace Example

class Example {
    public function __construct()
    {
        echo 'constructed';
    }
}
```

index.php

```
<?php use Example\Example;

$example = new Example;

echo 'here ok';
```

but when I runing it in browser, its error:

[This page isn’t workinglocalhost is currently unable to handle this request.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0LIK.png)

What am I wrong, any help?

Comment: Please share the error message, and your attempts to resolve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you haven't posted what your `composer.json`contains yet, at least you must have it in your `autoload`:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Example\\": "src"
        }
    }
}
```

In your `index.php`, you need to require the autoload from composer:

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php'; // add the autoloader

use Example\Example;

$example = new Example;

echo 'here ok';
```

Lastly, you need to run composer to reflect your changes:

```
php composer dump-autoload
```