# Namespace cant find class

Tags: php, namespaces, slim

I trying to include vendor package to my project with composer and then use namespaces.
Package github link: https://github.com/Veltix/passgate

I use Slim 4 framework for my project.

Error what I got while I tryed to Signup:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Veltix\PassGate' not found in
> /path/to/controller/AuthController.php
> on line 68
>
> Error: Class 'Veltix\PassGate' not found in
> /path/to/controller/AuthController.php
> on line 68

My code looks like this:

```
namespace App\Controllers\Auth;

...
use Veltix\PassGate;

...
class AuthController extends Controller
{
    ...

    public function postSignUp($request, $response)
    {

        ...

        $user = User::create([
            ..
            'password' => PassGate::hash($data['password']), // 68 Line error
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried to do `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: Yes I have. It doesnt work. @MehrdadDastgir

Comment: Did you run `composer install`? Well, ... how do you include the library on your project?

Comment: Seems you are using wrong class name. Try `use Veltix\PassGate\PassGate`

Comment: `Uncaught Error: Class 'Veltix\PassGate\PassGate'` @nima

Comment: `"autoload": {
     "psr-4": {
      "Veltix\\": "src/"
     }
    }`

Comment: The package you are using has a faulty composer.json. Its composer.json says the namespace `Veltix` is mapped to `src` directory, while it should say the namespace `Veltix\PassGate` is mapped to that directory, or it should define class `PassGate` under namespace `namespace Veltix`

Comment: `Veltix` is vendor `PassGate` is package/plugin however you call it. Class is defined as `PassGate`. Im trying to fix this composer package. I tryed `namespace Veltix` and got error `Uncaught Error: Class 'Path\To\Controller\PassGate' not found in` - still same 68 Line where I try `PassGate::hash($password)`. I want namespace like `Veltix\PassGate` so it is vendor name and package name/class name so I can call functions what are inside that like `public static hash( ) { }` @Nima

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63126941/14022841 I have similar like this but not working. @Viney

Comment: In file `vendor/veltix/passgate/src/PassGate.php` replace 'namespace Veltix\PassGate;` with `namespace Veltix; ` and keep everything else untouched.

Comment: This worked, but ... @Nima Why I cant use namespace `PassGate`?, because `PassGate` is package name and `Veltix` is vendor. Where Will be more package.

Comment: You can use that name, but the mapping should be defined correctly in composer.json. Right now there is a problem with psr-4 mappings in composer.json and the directory structure of the package.

Comment: How I should configure mappings the? and the directory structure?

Comment: That is something that should be done in packages code and composer.json not your project. Refer to my second comment please.

Comment: @Nima I want fix that package so it works well for everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your autoloading rules are incorrect - you specified that `src` directory maps to `Veltix` namespace, but all classes inside use `Veltix\PassGate` namespace. Change your autoloading rules to:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Veltix\\PassGate\\": "src/"
    }
}
```